# Updating a table only when unique constraint is not violated

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table:

```
Id   Account_Number  Csd_id   pk_id  dk_id
1       343          200      100     50
2       234          400      200     70
3       343          400      100     70
```

I have a unique constraint on `account_number`, `csd_id` and `pk_id`.

Now, I want to update all the `csd_id` to `200` where `csd_id` is `400` only where the above unique constraint is not violated.

Once the update is done, I have to delete the leftover records where the `csd_id` is `400`.

Comment: How can you have the data in the table, if you have a unique constraint on those three columns? The constraint is already violated (which Oracle wouldn't allow you to) - so something in what you said is not actually true. Please clarify.

Comment: the unique constraint is on combination of these 3 not individual.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The last two rows have exactly the same values in all three columns.

Comment: i have edited it and this is just the dummy data. In actual table the number of records are more than 1000.

Comment: Your first step is to writing a select query that finds out the rows that meet this rule. For starters it would be `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE csd_id = 200`

Comment: Are any of the columns non-nullable? That would make the job much simpler.

Comment: This is rather straight forward basic SQL knowledge. What have you tried so far yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You just need an `update` statement that includes a `not exists` clause to avoid an update where your constraint would be violated. And, of course, then you need a simple `delete` statement for the left over rows:

```
update tbl t1
   set t1.csd_id = 200
 where t1.csd_id = 400
   and not exists (
     select null
       from tbl t2
      where t2.account_number = t1.account_number
        and t2.pk_id = t1.pk_id
        and t2.csd_id = 200
   );

delete tbl where csd_id = 400;
```

**EDIT**

Very unlikely, but if nulls are possible for either `account_number` or `pk_id`:

```
update tbl t1
   set t1.csd_id = 200
 where t1.csd_id = 400
   and not exists (
     select null
       from tbl t2
      where (t2.account_number = t1.account_number or (t2.account_number is null and t1.account_number is null))
        and (t2.pk_id = t1.pk_id or (t2.pk_id is null and t1.pk_id is null))
        and t2.csd_id = 200
   );

delete tbl where csd_id = 400;
```

Comment: Will this work if there are nulls in `account_number` and/or `pk_id`? Looking at the Comments, I see I asked the OP whether the columns were nullable about three hours before you posted this answer; I still don't see a response from the OP. Nor do I see a mention of nulls in your Answer.

Comment: @mathguy: I added the nullable scenario for completeness, but I consider that a very unlikely edge case. In my view, the way null values are handled in multi-column unique constraints makes them unpractical for common use.